# Why don't browsers accept slightly misspelled URLs?

Tags: browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm north of 50, and can't always make the connection from my eyes to my fingers while looking at the screen rather than the keys, resulting in things like "www,something.tld" being entered into whichever program (Windows run dialog, browser, something else)

Wouldn't the browser developers have addressed minor flubs like this a LONG time ago, and accepted them for the most obvious result?

Or is there something else implied by the above that I'm missing?

dL

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact there there are now over a billion Web sites on the internet (http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/09/how-many-websites-are-there/408151/).

This means that there is a good chance that www.example.com may be a completely different Web site than www.exaample.com, www.examplee.com, etc.

Also, in your specific case with the comma, www,something.tld--modern Web browsers will usually do a Web search (using Yahoo, Google, Bing, etc.) for text you put in the address bar that **doesn't match a valid domain name** (especially when there is a comma in it), because it has no way of knowing if you *really* meant to put the comma in there.

Answer (score 0):

Computers only ever do what they're told to do. They will also take you literally when asking them to do something, no matter how ridiculous it may seem. That is their purpose, and it allows people to do ridiculous things with them - sometimes. It also allows for very similar yet distinct URLs.

Since commas aren't valid characters to use in filenames it is fairly safe to say they can't be used in URLs. As for why it hasn't been fixed, developers like to be lazy / efficient and there hasn't really been a need to fix it when most people will just use a search engine like Google and click links instead of manually entering addresses. Plus most people will have favourites in their browser to go to instead of searching each time.

Recently Chrome has gotten better with misspelled URLs and if a page doesn't exist it will offer to search for pages including similar words.

For example:

[image: Misspelled Suggestion Example]

There may be a plugin out there to convert all commas into stops but I am yet to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The number of websites is a good argument, but I think it cannot be applied to commas.

Although there are nearly 2 billion websites out there (https://www.millforbusiness.com/how-many-websites-are-there/) this is still not the reason for not fixing this kind of minor issues.

No website uses a comma in its URL. Accordingly, it's not possible to access any website with a web browser in case you type a comma instead of a dot.

I agree with the question and do not understand why this is still an issue.